# Render detail band at the bottom of the page before another detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with detail bands in JasperReports. The details band 1 will occupy more than one page since it has all the necessary information for the report. There are also two more detail bands that have to appear at the end of the first page and may have a lot of information and overflow on the next one (example with three pages)

The problem is that I cannot fix to botton the two detail 2 and detail 3 bands, showing the detail 1 band in the hole above

Example with detail 2 and 3 not overflow:

```
Page 1           Page 2 and following
Header           Header
Detail 1         Detail 1 continuation
Detail 2         Footer
Detail 3
Footer
```

[image: detail 2 and 3 not overflow]

Example with detail 2 overflow

```
Page 1         Page 2                     Page 3 and following
Header         Header                     Header
Detail 2       Deatil 1                   Detail 1 continuation
Detail 3       Detail 2 continuation      Footer
Footer         Footer
```

[image: detail 2 overflow]

Would someone know how to help me

Comment: In the first example you could put detail 2 and 3 in the page footer and configure the "print when" to page_count == 1.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that both example 1 and 2 can be given depending on the data, so it has to be valid for both examples and if I put detail 2 and 3 in the page footer and example 2 occurs, the footer does not allows overflow so it would give error